# How can we use iterators in q to apply a list of functions to each of a list of arguments?

Tags: kdb

In q/kdb, we can apply a function to a number of arguments, as below:

```
f each (1;2;3)
```

We can also apply a defined argument to a list of functions:

```
flist: (f1:{x+y+z},f2:{x+y-z},f3:{x-y+z});
flist  .\: 1 2 3
```

What is the most efficient way to combine both of these- to apply every function in a list to each value in a list as parameters. For example, to apply 3 unary functions, f1, f2 and f3, to a list containing values 1, 2 and 3 (producing 9 calls).

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the eachboth (') operator:

```
q)f1:1+;f2:2+;f3:3+
q)(f1;f2;f3) @' 10 20 30
11 22 33
```

or in the case of multi-argument functions,

```
q)g1:+;g2:-;g3:*
q)(g1;g2;g3) .' (2 1;3 2;2 2)
3 1 4
```

and if you want to apply each function to each value, you need to form a cross product first:

```
q)(@/)each(f1;f2;f3) cross 10 20 30
11 21 31 12 22 32 13 23 33
```

Comment: If we want to  apply each function to each value, how would we go about that? For example, if we want the following to insert both values into both lists?:

    `.abc.list:();
    .abc.list2:();
f1:{[aircraft].abc.list,:aircraft};
f2:{[aircraft].abc.list2,:aircraft};
(f1;f2) @' (exec distinct sym from data)`

Comment: I updated my answer, but @james-little suggestion to use `@/:\:` is probably better.

Comment: Your answer is on the money too- thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unary [apply-at](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/) `@` (since you are dealing with unary functions), in combination with each-left & each-right. For example:

```
q)({x+1};{neg x};{x*x}) @\:/: (1 2 3)
2 -1 1
3 -2 4
4 -3 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution James, exactly what I was looking for.